# A Besov norm estimate of analytic function based on Paley-Wiener theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-analysis, littlewood-paley-theory

Assume that $m$ is a bounded and analytic function over a sector $\Sigma_\omega$ and $m_e=m\circ \exp$. Hence $m_e$ is a bounded and analytic function over the strip 
$$
\{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid |\Im z|<\omega\}.
$$
I need to show that 
$$
\|m_e\mid_{\mathbb{R}}\|_{B_{\infty,1}^\alpha}\leq C\omega^{-\alpha}\sup_{|\arg z|<\omega}\|m(z)\|,
$$
where $B^\alpha_{\infty,1}$ denotes the Besov norm over $\mathbb{R}$. This estimate is from  the paper ''Banach spaces operator with a bounded  $H^\infty$ calculus''. 
An important step of the deduction is 
$$
(\star)\quad\|m_e\star\check{\phi}_n\|_{\infty}\leq \exp(-\omega 2^{|n|-2})\|m\|_\infty,
$$
where 
$$
\phi_{\pm n}(\xi)=\phi(\pm \xi \cdot2^{1-n})\quad \forall \xi\in\mathbb{R},
$$
with $\phi=(1-2|\xi-1|)_++(1/2-|\xi-3/2|)_+$. It claims that it is based on ``proof of Paley-Wiener theroem''.  But I don't know how to show $(\star)$ holds.